# How to decrement a variable while printing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Some `if` and `else`'s can be rewritten<sup>1</sup> and shortened<sup>2</sup> (codegolf-style) likewise, because booleans can act as integers in Python. For example `if a<b:return a` can be rewritten<sup>3</sup> as `return("",a)[a<b]`.

In this case (I simplified the condition for readability),

```
if a<b: print(a)
```

can be rewritten as both of the following:

```
print(("",a)[a<b]) 

(print(""),print(a))[a<b]
```

(if we ignore newlines, else `end=""` can be used).

I would like to decrement a variable `n` (the whole thing is in a while loop with `n` in its condition) when `a<b` is true on top of everything, eg.

```
if a<b: 
    print(a)
    n-=1
```

while using the syntax trick above.
 In C, `(n/n--)-1` is not only equal to 0, but also substracts 1 from `n`. In Python, I haven't found a way to do this. Some invalid syntaxes I tried:

```
print(("",a+(n/n--)-1)[a<b])

(print(""),(print(a);n-=1))[a<b]
```

**How to decrement the variable (and print `a`) when the condition is true using this "trick"?**

---

<sup>1,2,3</sup>: these statements aren't always true

Comment: Please don't do weird things.

Comment: @MarounMaroun It doesn't seem weird to me :) Anyhow, I'll think twice before posting a potentially weird question in the future. Thanks for noticing me!

Comment: Sorry beforehand to everyone, for wording titles isn't my area. Any guideline or  other proposal would be appreciated.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek in this case I believe the title is right, but I agree that the rest is weird;)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your question is well asked and clear. You can always ask questions like it in Stack Overflow.

Comment: `if a<b:return a` cannot be rewritten as `return("",a)[a<b]`, because it shouldn't return when `a >= b`. Similarly, your attempts to rewrite those `print` lines are also wrong.

Comment: Additional note: if you know that this is weird, and you only want to play code golf, you should make this clear in the question to avoid any backlash:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yeah, this was originally a code golfing attempt :)

Comment: `(print(""),print(a))[a<b]` doesn't do what you think it does. In fact, it *always* prints `a`.

Comment: Maybe: `n = (lambda:n,lambda:print(a) or n-1)[a<b]()`

Comment: @Thanks for pointing out the issue that it prints both times.and the lambda function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python isn't C. For one thing, Python doesn't have a decrement operator, so `print(n--)` won't work. For another, assignments in Python are statements, not expressions, so `print(n-=1)` won't work.

If you truly wanted your print statement to have side effects, it could invoke a function:

```
def decrement():
    global n
    n -= 1
    return n
print(decrement())
```

But don't. No one will expect that your print statement has side-effects, so everyone will be surprised when commenting out your print statement changes the program's result.

EDIT: I just noticed that this is a code golf question. In that case, my stylistic advice isn't really valid. Everyone expects golfed code to be weird.

Ps. If your goal is to change `if` statements into expressions, then play with `and` and `or`, which short circuit. For example:

```
a<b and (print(a), decrement())
```

Or use `if ... else` expressions

```
(print(a),decrement()) if a<b else None
```

Comment: I disagree on `In that case, my stylistic advice isn't really valid.`. Codegolf isn't the main part of the question :)

Comment: shouldn't you `return n`? this will print `None`, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 10
print(n // (n := n-1) - 1)

# (x := y) is the equivalent of x = y 
#but you can use it inside expressions 
#and it returns the new value of x

# finally a C simple assignment 

a = (b := 1)
print(a, b)
```

gives

```
0
1 1
```