# Don't understand why while(t-=1): is a SyntaxError

Tags: python, while-loop

I have been coding in C/C++ earlier.

In C++ the below code runs fine. It prints Hello 5 times.

```
   int t = 5; 
   
   while (t--)
   {
       cout << "Hello";
   }
```

The above loop works perfectly. When `t` becomes 0 loop condition will be false and loop will terminate.

But when I try a similar thing in Python:

```
t = 5
while (t-=1):
    print("Hello")
```

It gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

I know that, in python we can use 1 == True and 0 == False logic.

Then what's the issue in my Python loop?

Comment: In Python, 0 doesn't mean `False`. You should modify the condition to something like `while (not  (t -= 1) == 0)`

Comment: Well, looks like you just noticed that Python and C have different syntaxes. Here: Assignments are not allowed in expressions. Exception: the new `:=` operator.

Comment: In Python it's `while t := t - 1:`, but we would write `for t in range(5):` to loop five times.

Comment: This is that you don't know the Python language. Stackoverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Comment: There is no reasonable equivalent for `t--`. There **is** a reasonable equivalent for `--t` which is `t := t - 1` in current versions of python. An **unreasonable** way to implement `t--` is `(s:=t) and (t:=t-1) or s`... but this depends on the context in which `t--` is used. For example that expression will stop decrementing once reached `0`, if you want to go in the negatives you need something else

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149899/how-to-decrement-a-variable-while-printing-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C(++), unlike Python, returns the assigned value from assignments, and so they are valid expressions you can use in conditions etc. In Python, you can't use the even simpler `while t = 1:` because the value of the assignment `t = 1` is `None`, not `1`; and besides, it is not syntactically an expression - that's why you get a `SyntaxError`.

The walrus operator `:=` was introduced precisely to offer a way to do this; but the result is not idiomatic Python.

```py
# Requires Python >= 3.8; not a good example
t = 6 # Because the condition will be false and not print when you reach 0
while t := t-1:
    print('Hello')
```

There are places where having assignments as expressions is defensible, but this is really not an example of that. Python was consciously designed to avoid this type of side effect, which arguably makes C code more compact, but harder to understand at a glance, especially when you have expressions which contain multiple assignments.

The usual way to do this in Python would be

```py
for t in range(5):
    print('Hello')
```

or, if you really insist on counting backwards,

```py
for t in range(5, 0, -1):
    print('Hello')
```

More often than not, in Python, you really don't need an explicit loop to have the same thing many times.

```py
print('\n'.join(['Hello'] * 5))
```

or, if spaces instead of newlines are acceptable,

```py
print(*['Hello'] * 5)
```

Comment: Python's `print` supplies a newline at the end. You can avoid that with `print('Hello', end='')`; but again, many times you'd just provide the complete output as the argument to `print()` and then not need to explicitly add a newline after.

Answer (score 1):

Because `t -= 1` is not an expression, it's a statement. It's in essence:

```
t = t - 1
```

The expression is `t - 1`, the statement is `t = <some_expression>`

The `while` keyword requires an expression, which can be (1) a function call, or (2) a mathematical expression.

So, writing

```
while t -= 1:
```

is equivalent to:

```
while t = t - 1:
```

and is thus a syntax error.

(As a contrast, the C decrement operator `--` is an "expression with side effect")

Answer (score 0):

To print 'Hello' 5 times with `while`:

```
t = 5
while t:
    print("Hello")
    t -= 1
```

Prints:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```